# Excel: one "common" cell on multiple sheets - change it on one sheet, changes on all other sheets as well

Tags: excel

am working on a financial model with scenarios that apply to various sheets. Instead of picking the scenario from one specific sheet, I'd like to be able to select the scenario from any sheet and that the scenario then propagates on all other sheets. Without VBA, one common variable that is accessible from various sheets.
Here illustrated:

- I select one value in sheet1, this same cell takes the same value on sheet2 and sheet 3
- Now I work on sheet2, change this value, then this same cell takes that value on sheet 1 and 3
  Possible? Sounds like a input-output cell at the same time, but may work if there is a way to have a common reference?
  If not will I know how to play some tricks but would have been easier if common reference exists.
  Thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative that saves you having to go the original sheet to change the scenario:
On any of the sheets insert a ComboBox Form control. Use Format Control, Control tab, Cell Link to link the combobox to your "input" sheet cell. Put your list of scenarios on the same sheet and set the input range of the combobox to that list.

Copy the control to all the other sheets you want to select the scenario from. Each combobox will reflect the same value.

As suggested by Solar Mike - name the cell for clarity

Edit: Didn't finish what I was typing, sorry. *As suggested by Solar Mike - name the cell for clarity* and point the "common" cell on each sheet to the Cell Link on the Input sheet.

Comment: Combobox is the way, thank you CHill60

Answer (score 0):

You can have a sheet (sheet1) with a cell (A1) storing a number like vat rate.

Then from another sheet (sheet2) call that like so:

```
=sheet1!A1
```

Or you can give a cell a name and just call the name

Both require going to the original sheet to edit the value.

However you can just create a name in the name manager without having it on any sheet, which means you have to go into the name manager to edit it.

I find having an "info" or "constants" sheet is best, all visible and one place to find them.